# Различное отображение одинаковых кастомных View в сториборде

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Имеется кастомная View, созданная с .xib. Содержит в себе Label и Field. При добавлении 2-x штук в ViewController в сториборде естественно, что Label на сториборде отображается одинаковый для обоих View. Понятно, что в коде через аутлеты можно менять значение Label как угодно. А как изменить отображение Label для двух одинаковых View в сториборде?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, решение найдено, оно оказалось очень простым. Все делается с помощью аннотации @IBInspectable. Есть кастомная View, содержащая Label. Задача была в том, чтобы при добавлении на контроллер в сториборде 2 кастомных View отображался разный текст с возможностью изменить его строку из билдера.

```
@IBInspectable
var text: String! {
    get {
        return self.textLabel.text
    }
    set {
        self.textLabel.text = newValue
    }
}
```

textLabel - аутлет соответствующего Label'a

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов использовать свойство tag у Label:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]